# Вычисление пропорций цветов

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Дано:
 4 RGB цвета - A,B,C,D
 Цвет D получен в результате смешивания A,B,C.

Вопрос: 
 как получить пропорцию выбранного нами цвета(например А) в результирующем D?

Моя попытка решить:

1. Преобразуем A,B,C,D в CIELAB для использования результата в виде Vector3.
2. Строим треугольник где A,B,C вершины, D - центр масс(предположительно)
3. Из D строим перпендикуляры к AB и AC и получаем четырехугольник, который представляет собой площадь, которая является пропорцией искомого цвета.(предположительно)
4. Считаем площадь треугольника, и вычисляем отношение с результатом из пункта 3.

У меня затык в пункте 3, туго с математикой. Прошу помочь с алгоритмом(С++).
Так же возможно мой ход мыслей не правильный, в таком случае прошу представить ваш вариант решения данной задачи.

PS: CIELAB вполне ок, в задаче с 2-мя цветами результат отвечает ожиданиям.

Для лучшего понимания проблемы прикладываю пикчи:

Это слой, который содержит так называемые цветовые идентификаторы объекта(colorId), этим цветом заливается объект целиком.

[image: ColorID без сглаживания]
Этот слой содержит сглаживание:

[image: colorId + AA]

Нужно получить:
[image: альфа]

Поясню почему так. В данном случае объекты которые имеют зеленый и коричневый colorId выбраны, и их нужно отобразить. Причем мне нужно выделить их так на маске, что бы граница не была резкой. Для вычисления границ используются данные из слоев colorId и colorId + AA. В случаях когда рядом с пикселем граничат лишь 2 colorId, проблем с расчетом пропорций нет. Проблема когда 2+.

Варианты с блюрами\и различными сглаживаниями не катят. Нужно повторить 1 в 1 то что изображено на 3-й картинке, т.к. данный продукт используется в графике.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А почему бы не взять просто средневзвешенное?

```
result.r = (A.R * weight_A + B.R * weight_B + C.R * weight_C) /
               (weight_A + weight_B + weight_C);
```

и т. д.

---

По результатам дискуссии в чате, выяснилось следующее.

При сглаживании цветов цвет резцльтирующего пикселя будет (приближённо) оцениваться как средневзвешенное цветов исходных пикселей с некоторыми весовыми коэффициентами. Задача состоит в том, чтобы найти эти самые весовые коэффициенты. Причём под значением пикселя подразумевается его координаты в [цветовом пространстве LAB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAB) (как ни странно, это имеет определённый физический смысл).

Итак, вычисление. Пусть компоненты цветов *A*, *B*, *C* в цветовой модели LAB равны (*x*₁, *y*₁, *z*₁), (*x*₂, *y*₂, *z*₂), (*x*₃, *y*₃, *z*₃) соответственно, а компоненты результирующего цвета *D* — (*x*, *y*, *z*). Пусть неизвестные весовые коэффициенты равны α, β, γ. Имеем:

α ⋅ (*x*₁, *y*₁, *z*₁) + β ⋅ (*x*₂, *y*₂, *z*₂) + γ ⋅ (*x*₃, *y*₃, *z*₃) = (*x*, *y*, *z*)

Поскольку суммарный вес должен равняться 1, то α + β + γ = 1. Получаем систему

α ⋅ *x*₁ + β ⋅ *x*₂ + γ ⋅ *x*₃ = *x*
α ⋅ *y*₁ + β ⋅ *y*₂ + γ ⋅ *y*₃ = *y*
α ⋅ *z*₁ + β ⋅ *z*₂ + γ ⋅ *z*₃ = *z*
α + β + γ = 1

Поскольку точки должны лежать в одной плоскости, третье уравнение обязано быть следствием первых двух, убираем его. Заменяем γ = 1 − α − β, получаем:

α ⋅ *x*₁ + β ⋅ *x*₂ + (1 − α − β) ⋅ *x*₃ = *x*
α ⋅ *y*₁ + β ⋅ *y*₂ + (1 − α − β) ⋅ *y*₃ = *y*

или

α ⋅ (*x*₁ − *x*₃) + β ⋅ (*x*₂ − *x*₃) = *x* − *x*₃
α ⋅ (*y*₁ − *y*₃) + β ⋅ (*y*₂ − *y*₃) = *y* − *y*₃

Это система линейных уравнений с двумя неизвестными, решаем её стандартным образом.

Comment: добавил больше инфы в вопрос

Comment: @Bezarius: То есть, у вас есть смешанный цвет, а вы пытаетесь восстановить весовые коэффициенты? А **точная** формула, по которой цвет смешивался, есть?

Comment: Точной формулы нету. Перепробовал десятки способов, самый точный результат я смог получить благодаря модели Lab. Для случая с 2-мя цветами я рассчитываю так: auto ab = distance(a, b);
       auto bc = distance(b, c);
       val = bc / ab;

Comment: @Bezarius: В таком случае, мы пытаемся зареверсить неизвестный алгоритм? // А где на ваших рисунках A, B, C, D?

Comment: Нам не нужно реверсить неизвестный алгоритм, нам нужно просто рассчитать процентное соотношение цветов в цвете D, в данном случае цвет D это пиксель по центру на слое со сглаживанием. A,B,C это цвета на слое без сглаживания - коричневый, голубой, зеленый. Так как в случае с 2-мя цветами прокатило, я думаю и с 3-мя должно прокатить.

Comment: @Bezarius: Окей, тогда вопрос. Если у нас есть цвета c1(r1, g1, b1), c2(r2, g2, b2), c3(r3, g3, b3), и процентное соотношение — 50%, 30%, 20%, то каким будет (или: как рассчитать) итоговый цвет?

Comment: Это соотношение и есть конечный ответ :) Предположительно вышеописанный мною алгоритм должен дать правильный результат. Математики бы чутку :)

Comment: @Bezarius: Это-то я понимаю, но у нас-то стоит обратная задача: по итоговому цвету рассчитать весовые коэффициенты. Вот я и спрашиваю, как решается прямая: по весовым коэффициентам рассчитать итоговый цвет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29418/discussion-between-bezarius-and-vladd).